Language Localization Issue in Kendo UI Grid
I'm encountering an issue with language localization in my MVC web application when using the Kendo UI grid component. I've integrated the fr-FR.min.js script from Kendo UI v2019.3.1023, which successfully changes the grid language to French. However, when I attempt to use the latest version of kendo.culture.fr-FR.min.js, the grid language does not update as expected.
I've ensured that the file paths are correct and that the culture file is being loaded properly. Additionally, I've initialized the culture file according to the documentation, but the issue persists.
Could you please assist me in resolving this language localization issue? Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Are you getting any console error on your browser?
